# I need help identifying this connector

Tags: identification, connector

I am trying to figure out what connection I need to get back to a standard 4 pin.  This is the connection on the Ortur Laser Master 2.  I bought a rotary and it has a different connection.  I have a picture of it in another string because the image size was to big.  Can you please Identify this for me?  I have calipers if other information is required and thank you very much!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pitch and general dimensions please! Too hard to determine if it is 2mm,2.5mm 2.54mm etc..... Are there any markings on the connector? At a guess it is something that JST would manufacture. Their website has plenty of pictures.

Comment: You could perhaps go to the website of, say, Digikey or Mouser, and use their search capabilities. On Digikey, for example, you can see the categories of connectors, and then use your measurements to narrow down by pitch, dimensions of the housing, etc.  (this certainly looks like a Molex type of connector)

Comment: It is 12.45 mm wide and 3.25 mm thick.  I not sure hat you mean by pitch.  there are no markings.  What other information would be helpful?  keep in mind that I dont really know much about the connectors besides how to install them so be specific with information you need so I can make sure it is what you are asking for.  And I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Pitch is the distance between pin centers - measure the distance between the centers of the end pins, and divide by five (there are five-spaces-between-pins on a six pin connector).

Comment: ok so it could be 8 mm pitch.   I measured it and got 41.5 mm but they are thin and I might have pushed a little hard so I rounded down.. Does 8mm pitch sound right?

Comment: > got 41.5 mm   -- no, that's bigger than the width of the connector! > Does 8mm pitch sound right? -- Not at all. 12.45 mm wide / 6 = 2 mm pitch.

Comment: yeah Im not sure what I was measuring.  I just checked again, the width of the whole cable connection is 12.5 mm and in outer pin to outer pin is like 10.25 so probably 10.  so pitch should be 2.

Answer (score 3):

2 mm pitch wire-to-board connector, unlatched.

[My connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_keyword&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_2) identifies it as one of these:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - 2SH + 2CH
- Adam tech - 2SH-H + 2CH-H
- JST - KRW + PHN (crimp)
- JST - PH + PH PHN (crimp)
- Molex - 89400 + 87369
- Molex - Micro-Latch
- Sullins - SWR201 + SWH201
- TE - HPI-2 (1r 4w)
- Wurth - WR-WTB 620

I could narrow it down with better pictures, especially of the mate on the PCB. But, just from that one picture, I am going to guess [JST PH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199).

Comment: I had to get into photoshop but I updated better pictures of both PCB connection and cable connection.

Comment: This is more likely a 2.54mm XH connector based on common usage.

Answer (score 0):

These tend to be called XH2.54-6p connectors, which is one of the generic terms for JST brand XH connector in 6 pin configuration. It's highly cloned copied or knocked off.

This is a standard connector seen on Nema Stepper Motors for various CNC/Laser/3d Printers kits.

You can also find cables pre-made with xh2.54-6p to 4 pin Dupont (another misnamed connector) for use in your intended device on the usual fleabay or rain forest supply sites.

**of course it's better if you accurately measure the pin to pin distance (center to center). If you have a spare 0.1" or 2.54mm header you can just line them up side by side to compare.**

Comment: No: The [JST XH](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_keyword&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_2p5&s=XH%20(2.5m)) is larger, it has two ridges with hooks at the end, and the header has 2 thin slots. OP's is smaller and has a two ridges without hooks, and theheader has a wide rectangular opening. OP's connector is a 2 mm pitch PH header with a PH or PHN plug.

Comment: Details: [2 mm pitch PH header with a PH or PHN plug](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_keyword&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_2&s=PH%20%2B%20PH%20PHN%20(crimp)) (my site).

Comment: Hmm could be, that's a solid argument. I hope OP tries the comparing a 0.1" header to it to accurately get the pin pitch as their measurement attempts seem not to be working.